# Group data and filter results

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas-groupby

I have several data related to an identifier. 
I want to keep the most viewed Sub_ID for each ID.
I use Python 2.7. I can use panda if needed to faster the process but I'm not familiar with it.

Example:

```
--------------------------------
ID     |    Sub_ID    |   Views 
--------------------------------
345    |     4        |   120
345    |     2        |   20
555    |     10       |   33
345    |     3        |   12
122    |     4        |   540
345    |     4        |   10
122    |     1        |   300
555    |     8        |   133
```

I need some code to obtain as final result:

```
--------------------------------
ID     |    Sub_ID    |   Views 
--------------------------------
345    |     4        |   120 
555    |     8        |   133 
122    |     4        |   540
```

Comment: What was the problem when you tried to do that?

Comment: Also, to me it looks like you just deleted rows with an ID that already appeared. So you are not grouping anything?

Comment: @mkrieger1 I didn't do that as I don't know how to do, that's the purpose of my question :)

Comment: @Nils It is more than deleting ID, I want to keep the ID with Sub_id that have the most view. Also grouping may be not the good term.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No group-by needed, although there is probably a way to do it with `.groupby` as well.

Instead:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [345, 345, 555, 345, 122, 345, 122, 555],
                   'Sub_ID': [4, 2, 10, 3, 4, 4, 1, 8],
                   'Views': [120, 20, 33, 12, 540, 10, 300, 133]})
print(df.sort_values(['ID', 'Views'], ascending=False).drop_duplicates(subset='ID', keep='first'))
```

yields:

```
    ID  Sub_ID  Views
7  555       8    133
0  345       4    120
4  122       4    540
```

Comment: Perfect, just what I needed, And the sorting is really fast.